# The height of text between different browsers

Tags: javascript

I made an easy example and try to get the height of string.

```
jQuery(function () {
    var jqSpan = $('span');
    jqSpan.css({
        'font-family': 'Arial',
        'font-size': '24px',
        'font-weight': 'bold'
    });
    $('#result').text(jqSpan[0].offsetHeight);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DCBP9/1/

I found the value is different between the different browsers. I have used reset.css, but it's value still not the same.

For example: (Mac)
In my example, Chrome is 27, Firefox is 28, Opera is 25, and Safari is 27

I know each browser has its own render engine, but I want to know is it possible to let them identical.

Comment: In Chrome/Firefox (Linux) it's equally 28. Does it not have to do with `line-height` that may take different defaults? Try setting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 'line-height' property. But the thing is you need to set it to a block item. In that case you will always get the same height.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dDat4/2/

```
jQuery(function () {
var jqSpan = $('p');
jqSpan.css({
    'font-family': 'Arial',
    'font-size': '24px',
    'font-weight': 'bold',
    'line-height': '28px'
});
$('#result').text(jqSpan[0].offsetHeight);
```

});

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to use line-height, but I forgot it only works on block element.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve same height on all browsers, you need to consider two things:

1. Using [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) e.g. "Consolas".
2. Using fixed size font units: points.

Code would look like:

```
jqSpan.css({
    'font-family': 'Consolas',
    'font-size': '20pt',
    'font-weight': 'bold'
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCBP9/7/).

Showing 32 on both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks. The solution looks cool! But I want to let user select font-family, so it may not be monospaced font...

Comment: Sorry, in such case I fear you'll have to set fixed height as explained in the other answer.